# How to rename a winform without renaming the class

Tags: winforms

C# winforms, VS2015

In designer if I rename CustomerForm to frmCustomer, the class is renamed also to frmCustomer. I want my class remain unchanged (CustomerForm). Thanks

Comment: Can you not just change the code, `Public Class frmCustomer` back to `Public Class CustomerForm`? The designer is there to help so it will change code references.

Comment: I used Resharper to do so, but the instance also gets changed back to CustomerForm instead of frmCustomer

Comment: Ah sorry I see what you mean now. The designer property **Name** will be the same as the code so `Public Class CustomerForm` will be the same as the property **Name** in the designer. Unfortunately I don't believe it can be changed to be different.

Comment: Why don't you rename the C# filename to `frmCustomer` and set the designer to `CustomerForm`?

Comment: I don't suppose you mean `CustomerForm form = new CustomerForm(); form.Name = "frmCustomer";`?

Comment: For consistency My classes begin with capital letters, my instance names begin with small letters, my file names are named as my clss names. ex: class: CustomerForm, fiename:CustomerForm.cs, designer instance name should be: frmCustomer

Comment: Or do you simply mean `CustomerForm frmCustomer = new CustomerForm();`?

Comment: for consistency I name as follow:
class: CustomerForm
filename: CustomerForm.cs
designer instance should be named: frmCustomer

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot have the underlying code class named differently to the designer. Changing the **Name** property will change the class name. The only way would be if you create an instance of the form as @Enigmativity has shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the designer code and change the name there:

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // CustomerForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Name = "frmCustomer";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.CustomerForm_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
```

Not always a good approach as the designer might clobber this change at any time.